# How to do transformNodeToObject with MS XML 6.0

Tags: c++, msxml, msxml6

In MS XML 4.0 you could have variables (using C++ here)

```
IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr spDocSource;
IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr spDocResult;
IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr spDocStylesheet;
```

and then load them up and do a transformation like

```
spDocSource->transformNodeToObject(spDocStylesheet, vResultDoc);
```

But in 6.0 it appears the function `transformNodeToObject` is gone. How should I do it now? All documentation I find is either about the obsolete 4.0 or don't seem to mention anything about it.

Comment: Quoting from the doc on [`transformNodeToObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms766561(v=vs.85)): "_Implemented in: MSXML 3.0 and MSXML 6.0_". Are you sure it isn't available in v6.0? People seem to have used it with `msxml60.dll`, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58073638/1458097), for example.

Comment: @heapunderrun That's what the compiler says "class "MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocument2" has no member "transformNodeToObject"

Comment: @heapunderrun Ah, it seem the compiler didn't know what it was talking about. Appears to work despite what it says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is actually there. It's just your compiler that need a good whack with a mallet or another blunt object. Try doing a clean build.

Comment: Or one should question why the obsolete MSXML is used at all. Even MSXML 6 is 18 years old. The library was part of Internet Explorer, which only exists for compatibility purposes in all supported Windows versions. There are far better XML processing libraries

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I wouldn't use it for new development, but this was an update to old software.